# How do you determine if a view column is computed using the Lead or Lag functions as MS don't flag it as 'Iscomputed' in the sys.Columns view?

Tags: t-sql

Columns created using the window functions such as lead or lag do not show up as IsComputed in the sys.Columns view. This seems to be an oversight by Microsoft.

I need to determine when a column is not updatable as I use the column metadata to drive a lightweight ORM.

Any ideas?

p.s. Sql Server 2014 version 12.0.4100.1

Comment: `IsComputed` refer only to computed columns in a table. Views are not tables. Derived columns' schema definitions in query result metadata (e.g. OLE-DB and ODBC's query reflection system) are also not marked as computed either.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution using the following system function:

```
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = 'Select * From {your view name here}'

SELECT
    Source_Column
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set( @query, NULL, 1 )
```

to find the base table columns for the view. Computed columns of all types have no Source_Column.